# Mapping a nested struct with mongo'd db .Decode(&dto)

Tags: mongodb, go

I have a model that creates a JSON document with no issue but retrieving it results in the nested JSON object being empty.

```
func (r *CourseRepo) GetCourseById(ctx context.Context, id string) (Course, error) {
    clog := log.GetLoggerFromContext(ctx)

    var course Course

    objID, err := primitive.ObjectIDFromHex(id)
    if err != nil {
        return course, err
    }

    filter := bson.M{"_id": objID}

    err = r.collection.FindOne(ctx, filter).Decode(&course)
    if err != nil {
        clog.ErrorCtx(err, log.Ctx{"msg": "an error occurred while finding a course"})

        return course, err
    }

    return course, nil
}
```

Struct

```
type Course struct {
    ObjectId    primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id, omitempty"`
    Id          string             `json:"id"`
    Title       string             `json:"title"`
    Description string             `json:"description"`
    Lessons     string             `json:"lessons"`
    Duration    string             `json:"duration"`
    Details     struct {
        Title             string `json:"title"`
        Instructor        string `json:"instructor"`
        Introduction      string `json:"introduction"`
        Learn             string `json:"learn"`
        Topics            string `json:"topics"`
        Prerequisites     string `json:"prerequisites"`
        Goal              string `json:"goal"`
        AdditionalDetails string `json:"additionalDetails"`
        HighLevelOverview string `json:"highLevelOverview"`
    } `json:"course_details"`
}
```

result

```
{
    "data": {
        "ObjectId": "64953ac1bf06bfdd7936cad8",
        "id": "",
        "title": "Java Algorithms",
        "description": "An awesome course",
        "lessons": "4",
        "duration": "10 hours",
        "course_details": {
            "title": "",
            "instructor": "",
            "introduction": "",
            "learn": "",
            "topics": "",
            "prerequisites": "",
            "goal": "",
            "additionalDetails": "",
            "highLevelOverview": ""
        }
    },
    "metadata": "none"
}
```

From what I read .Decode should map the nest values too?

Comment: When I executed  code "course, err := repo.GetCourseById(ctx, "000000000000000000000000")
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }

 courseJson, err := json.Marshal(course)"    , I got the expected result {
  "ObjectId": "000000000000000000000000",
  "id": "5f3a5c4c9b4c9e3c9b3c6a1d",
  "title": "Introduction to MongoDB",
  "description": "This is a course about MongoDB",
  "lessons": "10",
  "duration": "2 hours",
  "course_details": {
    "title": "",
    "instructor": "",
    "introduction": "",
    ....,
    "additionalDetails": "",
    "highLevelOverview": ""
  }
}

Comment: @Mani yes `course_details` is empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON? But [the Go MongoDB driver works with BSON](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/go/current/fundamentals/bson/)

The struct tags are used to define how the Go struct fields should be mapped to the MongoDB document fields.
In your `Course` struct, you are using `json` tags, but the [`Decode` method](https://pkg.go.dev/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.12.0/mongo#Cursor.Decode) from the MongoDB driver in Go uses the `bson` tags to map the document fields to the struct fields.

To solve this issue, you should add `bson` tags to your struct fields, including the nested struct, to instruct the MongoDB driver how to decode the document into your struct.

```golang
type Course struct {
    ObjectId    primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"ObjectId"`
    Id          string             `bson:"id" json:"id"`
    Title       string             `bson:"title" json:"title"`
    Description string             `bson:"description" json:"description"`
    Lessons     string             `bson:"lessons" json:"lessons"`
    Duration    string             `bson:"duration" json:"duration"`
    Details     struct {
        Title             string `bson:"title" json:"title"`
        Instructor        string `bson:"instructor" json:"instructor"`
        Introduction      string `bson:"introduction" json:"introduction"`
        Learn             string `bson:"learn" json:"learn"`
        Topics            string `bson:"topics" json:"topics"`
        Prerequisites     string `bson:"prerequisites" json:"prerequisites"`
        Goal              string `bson:"goal" json:"goal"`
        AdditionalDetails string `bson:"additionalDetails" json:"additionalDetails"`
        HighLevelOverview string `bson:"highLevelOverview" json:"highLevelOverview"`
    } `bson:"course_details" json:"course_details"`
}
```

Note that you can have both `bson` and `json` tags on the same field. The `bson` tags are used when interacting with MongoDB (e.g., when calling `.Decode()`), and the `json` tags are used when marshaling/unmarshaling to/from JSON format.

Also, make sure that the field names in your `bson` tags match the field names in your MongoDB documents. For example, if the field in the MongoDB document is named `courseDetails` instead of `course_details`, you should change the `bson` tag to `bson:"courseDetails"`.